# Is there any faster method for this MATLAB script?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

The original script is

```
    Y = [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]';
    n = length(Y);
    Ym = zeros(n, n);
    for i=1:n
        index = find(Y==Y(i));
        Ym(i, index') = 1;
    end
```

then, the `Ym` is

```
    Ym =

 1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
Ym = bsxfun(@eq,Y,Y.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that logical indexing works faster than bsxfun on my computer. Here the sample times for different methods:

```
tic;
for j=1:10000
    Y = [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]';
    n = length(Y);
    Ym = zeros(n, n);
    for i=1:n
        index = find(Y==Y(i));
        Ym(i, index') = 1;
    end
end
disp('Method 1:');
toc;

tic;
for j=1:10000
    Y = [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]';
    n = length(Y);
    Ym = zeros(n, n);
    for i=1:n
        Ym(i, Y==Y(i)') = 1;
    end
end
disp('Method 2:');
toc;
tic;
for j=1:10000
    Y = [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]';
    n = length(Y);
    Ym = zeros(n, n);
    a=repmat(Y,1,n);
    b=repmat(Y',n,1);
    Ym(a==b)=1;
end
disp('Method 3:');
toc;

tic;
for j=1:10000
    Y = [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]';
    Ym = bsxfun(@eq,Y,Y.');
end
disp('Method 4');
toc
```

OUTPUT:

```
Method 1:
Elapsed time is 0.111412 seconds.
Method 2:
Elapsed time is 0.069617 seconds.
Method 3:
Elapsed time is 0.246780 seconds.
Method 4
Elapsed time is 0.103120 seconds.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for kindly providing these possible implementations and the comparison.  I've run your code several times, it seems the 4-th method is fastest. And The testing computer has no other programs running. The second method is the second best with a very little slower than the 4th method.

Comment: As I understand, the bsxfun should be roughly equal to second method. But as I noticed the anomaly on my computer, I figured I should share all methods whichever suits you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very appreciated for your sharing! In fact, I've encountered some performance problems thus I want to speed up those scripts that runs slow. But on the other hand, I found I have no more thoughts on how to speed them. Your sharing means a lot! Thanks! With regarding to the speed, I think it more or less depends on the running environments about hardware or software.